# How do I get Google Cloud Source file view to offer the EDIT button?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

The GC [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119130156/https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/using-source-browser) say

[image]

and show

[image]

but I get no EDIT button

[image]

How do I get the EDIT button?

Setup is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, ChrisJJ. As we head towards GA for Cloud Source Repositories, we're trimming out underused and half-baked features, of which this is both. It's particularly half-baked because you can't use it to create new files or folders, move files or folders around, delete files, keep files in sync with the cloud shell, etc.

So, we've pulled this feature (and are updating the docs appropriately). However, if you'd like to edit your files on the web, you can do so with the Cloud Shell directly (via nano, vi or emacs) or you can use the new code editor feature described here: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/10/introducing-Google-Cloud-Shels-new-code-editor.html

I think you'll find that this is a MUCH more full-featured editor experience and we're continuing to look at ways to make it even better.

Comment: " It's particularly half-baked because you can't use it to create new files or folders, move files or folders around, delete files, keep files in sync with the cloud shell," Doesn't sound half-backed to me. It's an Edit button. No-one expects it to offer anything but Edit.

Comment: "So, we've pulled this feature" Thanks for the insider info. "(and are updating the docs appropriately)." Updating the docs appropriately would include removing the false offer of the Edit button. The docs have been offering the Edit button for weeks of the Edit button has been missing. Good luck.

Comment: "you can use the new code editor feature described here:" Ah, a blog article. Suggestion: put that effort instead into updating the official documentation. "MUCH more full-featured editor experience" Thanks, I hope it will get proper documentation and I look forward to trying it.